# Custom segue not working in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, segue

I'm trying to create a custom segue. It doesn't work in the first time. I found a solution afterward by creating a new file extends UIStoryboardSegue and create a method called "perform". It works right now without using prepareSegue in ViewController. I'm copied my previous codes from preparedSegue to "Perform" func in new UIStoryboardSegue file. It print out the message but the delegate doesn't work.

**View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**Custom Segue**

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
override func perform() {
    NSLog("Perform");
    let toViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
}
}
```

I placed breakpoint in every func in Transition Manager, none of them execute and stop.

**Segue settings:**

[image]

**Problem:** TransitioningDelegate is not working

Full sources codes: [here](http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `perform` implementation doesn't *do* anything:

```
override func perform() {
    let toViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
}
```

All you do is create a view controller, give it a transitioning delegate, and then throw it away. You do not perform any transition! But that is exactly the job of a segue. It isn't clear what you can possibly be expecting to happen.

If the idea is that this is supposed to be a present (modal) segue, then you should *make* it a present (modal) segue in the storyboard, specify your custom segue class, and then, in your `perform` implementation, call `super` to do the actual presentation:

```
override func perform() {
    let toViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
    super.perform() // this will work, _if_ you have specified a present (modal) segue
}
```

Alternatively, your `perform` could perform the presentation itself, by calling `presentViewController:...` on the source view controller with the destination view controller as parameter.

But *your* `perform` does nothing. Nothing will come of nothing.